# Check If a Selected File is a Text Editor

Tags: java

I have a program that does some file IO functions. I am using a FileDialog to allow the user to select the TextEditor which they would like results to be opened in. My question is this: Is it possible to verify that the selected file is actually a text editor?

Here is what I have in the GUI:

```
private JMenuBar createMenuBar() {
    JMenuBar jmb = new JMenuBar();
    JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("Settings");
    JMenuItem setEditor = new JMenuItem("Set Text Editor");
    setEditor.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                FileDialog fd = new FileDialog(frame, "Choose a file", FileDialog.LOAD);
                fd.setDirectory("C:\\");
                fd.setVisible(true);
                String path = fd.getDirectory() + fd.getFile();
                if (!path.equals("nullnull")) {
                    if(fileIsTextEditor(path)) { // How to code fileIsTextEditor(path)?
                        LogUtils.setTextEditor(path);
                    }
                    else {
                        //handle invalid text editor selected
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(Exception err) {
                
            }
        }   
    });
    fileMenu.add(setEditor);
    jmb.add(fileMenu);
    return jmb;
    
}
```

Here is my write function in a Static Util class:

```
public static void writeToFile(File outFile) {
    try{

          Files.write(Paths.get(outFile.toString()), results.toString().getBytes(), StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
          new ProcessBuilder(textEditor, outFile.toString()).start();
          //
          results.setLength(0);
      }
      catch(Exception e){
          System.out.println(e);
          try {
            java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().edit(new File(outFile.toString()));
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
}
```

Comment: In a word:  No.  (Also, you are not using FileDialog’s getDirectory and getFile methods correctly.  And `path.equals("nullnull")` is… a really wrong way to check for user cancelation.  You only have to check [whether getFile() returned null.](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/FileDialog.html#getFile()))

Comment: Short answer is "No". A longer answer might be to use platform-specific API to check if the executable is associated with `.txt` files, for example, or have a list of popular names of editor executables.

Comment: You would require a list of all possible text editors, then check if the file is an executable. Or do you mean to check if the file is editable text?

Comment: How many "users" know the file name and path of the Notepad, Wordpad, and Word applications?  You might want to let the user select a text editor application from a JComboBox and you fire up the correct process.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc Is there a way to start a process without knowing the path to its executable? Different users may have their text editors installed in different places.

Comment: How many "users" do you know with their own downloaded text editors?

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc The users that I know all have downloaded text editors, because they are all programmers.

Answer (score 0):

In the comments, the OP asked

```
Is there a way to start a process without knowing the path to its executable? 
Different users may have their text editors installed in different places.
```

I don't think you can start a process without the full path to the executable.

I was curious, so I wrote a Java class to read my disks, report on the number of directories and files on my disks, and give me the full path to the executables.

Here are the results after about 30 tests on my system.

```
Searching for the following programs: [notepad.exe, wordpad.exe, soffice.exe]

Number of directories searched: 135,331
Number of files searched:       559,262

C:\Windows\notepad.exe
C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\notepad.exe
C:\Program Files\Windows NT\Accessories\wordpad.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenOffice 4\program\soffice.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows NT\Accessories\wordpad.exe
C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft-windows-notepad_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.19041.1081_none_e3f87355251e8c43\notepad.exe
C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft-windows-wordpad_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.19041.1151_none_a28a8e43220f257d\wordpad.exe
C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft-windows-wordpad_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.19041.1202_none_a27aa61d221bdc5c\wordpad.exe
C:\Windows\WinSxS\wow64_microsoft-windows-notepad_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.19041.1_none_2f60455143be03e9\notepad.exe
C:\Windows\WinSxS\wow64_microsoft-windows-wordpad_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.19041.1_none_ee00310940a3cd37\wordpad.exe
C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft-windows-notepad_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.19041.1081_none_e3f87355251e8c43\f\notepad.exe
C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft-windows-notepad_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.19041.1081_none_e3f87355251e8c43\r\notepad.exe
C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft-windows-wordpad_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.19041.1151_none_a28a8e43220f257d\f\wordpad.exe
C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft-windows-wordpad_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.19041.1151_none_a28a8e43220f257d\r\wordpad.exe
C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft-windows-wordpad_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.19041.1202_none_a27aa61d221bdc5c\f\wordpad.exe
C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft-windows-wordpad_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.19041.1202_none_a27aa61d221bdc5c\r\wordpad.exe
C:\Program Files\Papyrus Author\Modules\filter\program\soffice.exe
C:\Windows\servicing\LCU\Package_for_RollupFix~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~19041.1165.1.8\amd64_microsoft-windows-notepad_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.19041.1081_none_e3f87355251e8c43\f\notepad.exe
C:\Windows\servicing\LCU\Package_for_RollupFix~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~19041.1165.1.8\amd64_microsoft-windows-notepad_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.19041.1081_none_e3f87355251e8c43\r\notepad.exe
C:\Windows\servicing\LCU\Package_for_RollupFix~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~19041.1165.1.8\amd64_microsoft-windows-wordpad_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.19041.1151_none_a28a8e43220f257d\f\wordpad.exe
C:\Windows\servicing\LCU\Package_for_RollupFix~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~19041.1165.1.8\amd64_microsoft-windows-wordpad_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.19041.1151_none_a28a8e43220f257d\r\wordpad.exe
C:\Windows\servicing\LCU\Package_for_RollupFix~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~19041.1237.1.10\amd64_microsoft-windows-notepad_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.19041.1081_none_e3f87355251e8c43\f\notepad.exe
C:\Windows\servicing\LCU\Package_for_RollupFix~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~19041.1237.1.10\amd64_microsoft-windows-notepad_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.19041.1081_none_e3f87355251e8c43\r\notepad.exe

Elapsed execution time: 7 minutes, 46 seconds
```

It's not a quick process.  What surprised me was the number of copies of Notepad and Wordpad that I had on my computer.  Even if the user never installed a single text processor, you still have to figure out which Notepad is the one with the desktop icon.

Here's the complete runnable code I used to get the test results.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class FullPath {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FullPath fp = new FullPath();
        fp.displayFullPath();
    }
    
    private List<File> directoryNames;
    private List<String> fileNames;
    
    public FullPath() {
        this.directoryNames = new ArrayList<>();
        this.fileNames = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    
    public void displayFullPath() {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        
        String[] programs = { "notepad.exe", "wordpad.exe", "soffice.exe" };
        System.out.println("Searching for the following programs: " 
                + Arrays.toString(programs));
        System.out.println();
        
        createFileList();
        System.out.println("Number of directories searched: " + 
                String.format("%,d", directoryNames.size()));
        System.out.println("Number of files searched:       " + 
                String.format("%,d", fileNames.size()));
        System.out.println();
        List<String> fullPathsList = findFullPath(programs);
        
        for (String s : fullPathsList) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
        System.out.println();
        
        long elapsedTime = (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime + 500) / 1000;
        int minutes = (int) (elapsedTime / 60L);
        int seconds = (int) (elapsedTime % 60L);
        System.out.println("Elapsed execution time: " + minutes + 
                " minutes, " + seconds + " seconds");
    }

    private void createFileList() {
        File[] roots = File.listRoots();
        for (int index = 0; index < roots.length; index++) {
            getFileList(roots[index]);
        }
        
        for (int index = 0; index < directoryNames.size(); index++) {
            getFileList(directoryNames.get(index));
        }
    }

    private List<String> findFullPath(String[] filenames) {
        List<String> fullPathsList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int index = 0; index < fileNames.size(); index++) {
            String s = fileNames.get(index);
            for (int jndex = 0; jndex < filenames.length; jndex++) {
                String t = filenames[jndex].toLowerCase();
                if (s.toLowerCase().endsWith(t)) {
                    fullPathsList.add(s);
                }
            }
        }
        
        return fullPathsList;
    }
    
    private void getFileList(File directory) {
        File[] files = directory.listFiles();
        if (files != null) {
            for (int index = 0; index < files.length; index++) {
                if (files[index].isDirectory()) {
                    directoryNames.add(files[index]);
                } else {
                    try {
                        fileNames.add(files[index].getCanonicalPath());
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is how I got my desired functionality:

```
private JMenuBar createMenuBar() {
    JMenuBar jmb = new JMenuBar();
    JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("Settings");
    JMenuItem setEditor = new JMenuItem("Set Text Editor");
    setEditor.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                FileDialog fd = new FileDialog(frame, "Choose a file", FileDialog.LOAD);
                fd.setDirectory("C:\\");
                fd.setVisible(true);
                String path = fd.getDirectory() + fd.getFile();
                if (!path.equals("nullnull")) {
                    try {
                        //Try to open the output file (a .txt file), then kill it immediately so it doesn't actually open.
                        Process p = new ProcessBuilder(path,la.getOutFile().toString()).start(); 
                        p.destroy();
                        LogUtils.setTextEditor(path);
                    }
                    catch(Exception e1) {
                        //If the selected file is not a text editor, it will not know how to open a .txt file
                        //and the process throws an exception.
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,
                                "Select a valid text editor!",
                                "Invalid Text Editor",
                                JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(Exception err) {
                
            }
        }   
    });
    fileMenu.add(setEditor);
    jmb.add(fileMenu);
    return jmb;
    
}
```

Only way this would fail (I think) would be if the selected file *can* open a .txt file, but still isn't a text editor. Please let me know if this might cause problems.

**EDIT:** I undeleted this post because I want to know more about this approach.

It seems to me that the following is true:

Exception will be thrown as desired:

1. If the selected file is not executable
2. If the selected file is executable but cannot take a 2nd param in the ProcessBuilder

The only way this approach "breaks" is if the selected file is executable and it can take a 2nd param in the processbuilder, but it still isn't a text editor. This seems desirable to me since it drastically cuts down on the probability of the user selecting a non text editor.

Comment: "If the selected file is not a text editor, it will not know how to open a .txt file and the process throws an exception": no it doesn't. It might return a non-zero exit code, if you're lucky. Processes don't throw exceptions. Any exception arising from this code relates to a failure to execute the process *at all.*

Comment: Ok but it's definitely throwing an exception. So do you see any major issues with this besides where the exception will come from? Would it possibly not throw exceptions when I want it to (i.e the process starts without any exceptions for a non text editor)?

Comment: It's probably throwing an exception because the file isn't an executable at all. Impossible to say until you provide the exception, of course. You're barking up the wrong tree completely here.

Comment: You're right. I tried with Acrobat and it didn't throw an exception. I'm going to delete this.